# How to read from file line by line using ajax request while file is written by other program using java?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp

In my project,
1) I have added logger using logback. The logger writes in a file while running a project.

2) I want to read this file while it is being written by logger and display output of it on html/jsp page.

3) To read file I want to send an ajax request from html/jsp page and display output as line by line. i.e. read one line and display it on html page.

Here is what I did-----

```
  //To read file 
  try {
        // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
        FileReader fileReader = 
            new FileReader(fileName);

        // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
            new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            out.println(line);
        }   
        bufferedReader.close();         
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Unable to open file '" + 
            fileName + "'");                
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Error reading file '" 
            + fileName + "'");                  
         // ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And my html page is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">       </script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function funReadFile(){
//alert("ok");

$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
//    contentType: "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
    url: '/manageCollector/readFile',
    success : function (response){

        $("#myResponse3out").html(response);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('error ' + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
    }
});
}

</script> 
</head>
<body onload = "funReadFile()">
<textarea  name="textarea" id="myResponse3out" rows="27" cols="70" ></textarea>
<h2>Test</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

How do I Read file line by line and display it??

Comment: The code seems correct what is the problem you are facing. Is it in reading or displaying?

Comment: I want to read like - read line1, display it . read line2, display it on html page.
But rightnow whole file contents get displayed on html page. 
It seems like read a file in single operation and displayed its contents..

Comment: but do you want to display line by line?..On some click event or animation ?

Comment: not on click event but like if you install anything on linux it shows different messages while installing, want to do same.

Comment: AJAX isn't the way to do this because you'll have to poll for each update. Look at connecting a websocket from the browser to the server and have the server push the lines as they are written using a custom log appender

Comment: @ Nick so what should I use to achieve this??

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/websocket.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can play with JQuery animation to display constants line by line..

```
$("#animate").click(function() {
    $("#content")
        .animate({"height": "100px"}, {"queue": false, "duration": 500})
        .animate({"width": "250px"}, 500);
});
```

or you can use Jquery Log Viewer libraries available on internet.. refer [this](http://blog.cozycloud.cc/tutorial/2013/03/12/how-to-display-a-log-file-in-the-browser-with-socket-io/) link